# beautifulsoup: Parse Span Title

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a html page, I have successfully got to the sub area of the tree of the html dom but I am stuck in a place where there are span tags.

example: I initially parse the page as follows:

```
        user_url = base_url + str(user_id) + "/" + display_name
        user_page = urllib2.urlopen(user_url)
        souping_page = bs(user_page)
        badges = souping_page.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'badges'})
```

badges will give me following:

```
<span><span title="3 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">3</span></span><span title="23 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">23</span></span><span title="43 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">43</span></span></span>
```

But I am trying to extract `<span title="3 gold badges">` and all the other `span title` attributes by traversing the dom structure. How can I do that in beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this:

```
>>> badges.span.span
<span title="3 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">3</span></span>
```

Comment: @alKid looks like its missing `<span title="23 silver badges">`