# BeautifulSoup consecutive blocks

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse my crawled html data,
The pattern I am looking at is

```
<div>
....
</div>
<p>
...
</p>
```

The content I care about is always enclosed with div followed by a *p* clause. Of course there are other stand-alone  *div* and *p* tags in the html, but the *p* followed by *div* are unique patterns that I want

Help know how to achieve query consecutive tags in beautifulSoup is very appreciated

Comment: Answered by for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122307/beautifulsoup-parse-span-title and many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are relevant [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling), [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings), [`.find_next_sibling()` and `.find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) methods that can help you to locate the `div` and `p` siblings:

```
div = soup.find("div", id="test")
p = div.find_next_sibling("p")
```

You can also use the ["adjacent" CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
soup.select("div#test + p")
```